# Criterion versus Convergent Validity

Tags: test, validation

I have some difficulties distinguishing criterion and convergent validity. According to Wikipedia, the difference is that criterion validity really focuses on *predicting* scores on another test, whilst converging validity is concerned with finding correlations between tests or variables that are *theoretically assumed* to be related (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_validity; To avoid any confusion: I know that concurrent validity is a subtype of criterion validity). 
However, I found a multiple choice question online that confused me:

*Scores on a final exam are related to student grade point average, the amount of time spent studying for the exam, and class attendance. What type of validity is demonstrated in this case?
A) convergent validity 
B) discriminant validity
C) criterion validity*

Apparently, the right answer is A), but I think you could still argue for C) in the following manner:
Scores on the final exam is the outcome measure and GPA, amount of time spent studying, and class attendance predict it.